# How to "de-elevate" authority in call to bat file

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, batch-file

I've got 3 `.bat` files in a directory. Two must be run with administrator privileges. One must be run without (full disclosure, I'm not sure why. It installs a windows service, and the service does not work if the `.bat` is called as an admin).

I'd like to keep them all in the same place for simplicity's sake, so I can easily switch between them in them same Command Prompt, which I'm running as an administrator. Unfortunately, that means I cannot correctly call the third script, as it's inheriting admin privileges.

The script is pretty straightforward:

`start /DC:\path_to_script script.bat`

Is there a way to "de-elevate" the call to that `.bat` file so it runs without admin rights?

Comment: Keep them in the same place but run a different cmd not as an admin and run this bat from that one.

Comment: @EBGreen the goal is to be able to run them from the same prompt. Eventually the implementation will move where we won't be able to split it up like that.

Comment: Use the solution proposed in [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17679701/run-batch-as-admin-auto-elevate-and-then-de-elevate)

Answer (score 3):

`runas /trustlevel:0x20000 script.bat`

0x20000 means "basic user".

This does exactly what you want. script.bat gets run unprivileged.

Please note:
The effect of `/D<path>`  given as parameter to `START` can also be achieved by running
`runas /trustlevel:0x20000 <fullpath>\script.bat`
and placing 
 `cd /D %˜p0` as first line in the script. (%˜p0 expands to the path of the script itself).